# Truncated cylinder in PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I would like the surface of the cylinder to reach the blue arcs towards left (`y-axis`) but not passing through them.

How can I achieve that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
    axis lines=middle, ticks=none,
    zmin=-2, zmax=2,
    xmin=-3, xmax=3,
    ymin=-1, ymax=3,
    view/h=125, view/v=25
    ]

    \addplot3[%
    opacity = 0.02,
    fill opacity=0.5,
    mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
    surf,
    colormap/hot,
    faceted color=black,
    z buffer = sort,
    samples = 50,
    variable = \u,
    variable y = \v,
    domain = 0:360,
    y domain = -3:3,
    ]
    ({cos(u)}, {max(v,cos(v))}, {sin(u)});

    % ARCS
    \addplot3[%
    variable= \t,
    mesh,
    blue!80!,
    semithick,
    samples=30,
    opacity = 0.025,
    z buffer = sort,
    domain= 0:180,
    ] 
    ({sin(t)}, {sin(t)}, {cos(t)});

    \addplot3[%
    variable= \t,
    mesh,
    blue!80!,
    semithick,
    samples=30,
    opacity = 0.025,
    z buffer = sort,
    domain= 0:-180,
    ] 
    ({sin(t)}, {-sin(t)}, {cos(t)});

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you were almost there. I just replaced `cos(v)` by `abs(cos(u))`. (**EDIT**: I also removed one `\addplot3`, which was redundant after replacing `sin(u)` by `abs(sin(u))` and extending the range to `0:360` in the other.)

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
    axis lines=middle, ticks=none,
    zmin=-2, zmax=2,
    xmin=-3, xmax=3,
    ymin=-1, ymax=3,
    view/h=125, view/v=25
    ]

    \addplot3[%
    opacity = 0.02,
    fill opacity=0.5,
    mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
    surf,
    colormap/hot,
    faceted color=black,
    z buffer = sort,
    samples = 50,
    variable = \u,
    variable y = \v,
    domain = -180:180,
    y domain = 0:3,
    ]
    ({cos(u)}, {max(v,abs(cos(u)))}, {sin(u)});

    % ARCS
    \addplot3[%
    variable= \t,
    mesh,
    blue!80!,
    semithick,
    samples=30,
    opacity = 0.025,
    z buffer = sort,
    domain= 0:360,
    ] 
    ({sin(t)}, {abs(sin(t))}, {cos(t)});

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I have to admit that I could not find out how to achieve that with LaTeX code but did not look for a mathematical solution either. The `absolute value` of the second parametric function is just brilliant! Thank you.