# Creating a bent 3D pipe in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles

I'm trying to create a bent/curved 3D pipe. I have only managed to place 2 cylinders at 90 degrees to each other. How can I join them with curved lines and remove the un-needed parts of the two cylinders?

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[cylinder, draw, shape aspect=1,rotate=200,minimum height=1cm,
      fill=white,fill opacity=1]{} ;
    \node[cylinder, draw, shape aspect=1,rotate=330,minimum height=0.8cm,
     fill=white]{} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/404273.

Comment: The L-turn part is just a quarter of torus. And then you extend it with straight cylinder.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you can `\draw` an `arc` with option `double` and place ellipses at each end. Note the `double distance` should account for the line thickness to get a smooth join. The ellipses are filled white to cover the ends of the doubled line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[double distance={10mm-.4pt}] (45:2) arc (45:135:2);
    \draw[fill=white, rotate around={45:(45:2)}](45:2) ellipse(5mm and 3mm);
    \draw[fill=white, rotate around={45:(135:2)}](135:2) ellipse(3mm and 5mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can extend the straight segments if you wish. Use `node` for easy placement of the ellipses.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[double distance={10mm-.4pt}] (0,0)node(a){}--++(1,1) arc (135:45:2)--++(1,-1)node(b){};
    \draw[fill=white, rotate around={135:(a)}] (a) ellipse(5mm and 3mm);
    \draw[fill=white, rotate around={135:(b)}] (b) ellipse(3mm and 5mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This can be turned into a macro `\pipebend` that takes 5 arguments (one optional):

```
\pipebend[<extra length>]{<pipe diameter>}{<start angle>}{<end angle>}{<bend radius>}
```

So the code

```
\pipebend[1cm]{1.5cm}{190}{60}{3cm}\hspace{-5cm}\pipebend[1cm]{2cm}{135}{45}{2cm}\hspace{1cm}\pipebend{1cm}{225}{315}{2cm}
```

Produces the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\pipebend}[5][0]{\tikz{
    \draw[double distance={#2-.4pt}] (0,0)node(a){}--++({#3+(sign(#4-#5))*90}:#1) arc (#3:#4:#5)--++({#4+(sign(#4-#5))*90}:#1)node(b){};
    \draw[fill=white, rotate around={#3:(a)}] (a) ellipse(.5*#2 and .3*#2);
    \draw[fill=white, rotate around={#4:(b)}] (b) ellipse(.5*#2 and .3*#2);
}} %\pipebend[<extra length>]{<diameter>}{<start angle>}{<end angle>}{<bend radius>}

\begin{document}

\pipebend[1cm]{1cm}{190}{45}{3cm}\hspace{-5cm}\pipebend[1cm]{1cm}{135}{45}{2cm}\hspace{1cm}\pipebend{1cm}{225}{315}{2cm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion in TIKZ only from above (sorry for the lack of artistry):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\pgfdeclarelayer{bg} 
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    %cylinder
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip[rotate=45] (-0.5,-0.25) rectangle (0.5,-1.6);
            %\draw[red,rotate=45] (-0.5,-0.25) rectangle (0.5,-1.6);
            \node[cylinder,draw=black,fill=white,thick,aspect=0.9,minimum height=3cm,minimum width=1cm,rotate=-45] (A) {};
        \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
    \node[cylinder,draw=black,thick,aspect=0.9,minimum height=3cm,minimum width=1cm,rotate=-135] (A) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}

    
    \draw[smooth,rounded corners] (-0.178,-0.528) -- (0,0) --(0.528,0.178);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]