Drawing the Steinmetz solid with TikZ
I want to draw the Steinmetz solid, the volume enclosed by two cilinder of same radius intersecting orthogonaly.

I have so far been able to draw the circles in 3D and the lines till their intersecting point.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\def\rotx{60}
\def\rotz{110}
\def\eps{0.5}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{\rotx}{\rotz}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords][scale=0.75]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]

% The axis:
\draw[dashed,-latex] (-5,0,0) -- (6,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[dashed,-latex] (0,-5,0) -- (0,6,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[dashed,-latex] (0,0,-5) -- (0,0,6) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

\draw [very thick,blue](0,-3-\eps,0) [y={(0,0,1)}] circle (3);
\draw [very thick,blue](0,3+\eps,0) [y={(0,0,1)}] circle (3);
\draw [very thick,red](-3-\eps,0,0) [x={(0,0,1)}] circle (3);
\draw [very thick,red](3+\eps,0,0) [x={(0,0,1)}] circle (3);

\foreach \angle in {0,10,...,360}
        {
        %calculate the sine and cosine of the angle
        \tdplotsinandcos{\sintheta}{\costheta}{\angle}%
        % draw the lines
        \draw[thin, blue]  (3*\costheta,-3-\eps,    3*\sintheta) -- (3*\costheta,{-3*abs(\costheta)},3*\sintheta)
                           (3*\costheta,{3*abs(\costheta)},3*\sintheta) -- (3*\costheta,3+\eps,      3*\sintheta);
        \draw[thin, red]   (-3-\eps,    3*\costheta,3*\sintheta) -- ({-3*abs(\costheta)},3*\costheta,3*\sintheta)
                           ({3*abs(\costheta)},3*\costheta,3*\sintheta) -- (3+\eps,      3*\costheta,3*\sintheta);
        }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

that renders as:

but I am taking a black eye at drawing the intersecting elipses and hiding the lines that are not supposed to be visible.
Are there automated ways to do this in TikZ and even to do a better picture of the solid, possibly using the shaded surface?
Added Sep 14, 2024: After realizing that it would be harder to get a good looking picture from TikZ and a prompts from @Jasper and from @PauloNey, I went to dig a bit deeper on Asymptote. It became imediate clear that the syntax for 3D was easier and the results a lot better. With the code
\documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
 \begin{document}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{asy}
  import graph3;
  import solids;
  pen myBlue = cmyk(1.00, 0.15, 0, 0);
  pen myRed = cmyk(0, 1.00, 1.00, 0);

  size(0,150);
  currentprojection=orthographic(1,1/1.7,1/1.6);

  // usage revolution r = cylinder(start,radius,length,ax);
  revolution r=cylinder(O,1,2.8,X);
  draw(surface(r),myBlue,render(merge=true));
  revolution r=cylinder((1.4,-1.4,0),1,2.8,Y);
  draw(surface(r),myRed,render(merge=true));
 \end{asy}
 \end{document}

one can get:

but it is clear that ligthing is happening in one cylinder as if the other were not there, that is, on each independent of the other.

I'm not sure how pgfplots implements surfaces overlapping each other. A shortcoming of the pgfplots implementation is that separate surfaces are just drawn on top of each other, while being drawn properly individually. An implementation in plain tikz would be valuable because it would overcome this limitation. I'd like to see a solution to this.

@Jasper the same is true for pgf/tikz generally. everything renders in order. there is no concept of 3d. you can put things on different layers so you specify things in one order and they're drawn in another, but you have to specify what and when. this kind of drawing really needs a programme designed to draw 3d and not just 2d. so gnuplots (which can be integrated into tikz), asymptote - even metapost I believe has some 3d capacity). as far as I know, the limitations in pgfplots on this score are just a function of those in pgf/tikz.

I understand, @cfr. I was just mentioning this because pgfplots does do a really good job at "faking" it with skillful layering, despite being 2d in nature and being built on top of tikz/pgf. I was suggesting that since it was possible to implement this capability in pgfplots, that it should also be possible to do it on a more fundamental level in tikz - enabling the user to do it with separate surfaces combined. I've been meaning to learn asymptote, it looks pretty cool. Thank you for the gnuplots comment by the way.

Circles are drawn in the xy plane.  While changing the scale to draw in the xz or yz planes works, it does not easily adapt to other planes  A rotated coordinate system would work better.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254820/tikz-pair-of-compasse-rendering-contest/254866?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C29.6578#254866

Read Section 63.4 of the TikZ Manual: Currently a number of things are not working, due to the fact PGF uses 2D coord system underwater, and perspective projection is a non-linear affine transformation which needs to be aware of all three coordinates. These three coordinates are currently lost when processing a 3D coord. Issues include, but possibly are not limited to:• Keys like shift, xshift, yshift not working • Keys like rotate around x, rotate around y, and rotate around z are not working • Most keys from the 3d library are unsupported.
It is nearly hopeless to pursue a solution in TikZ.

You are much better off pursuing a solution in Asymptote.

Both mine and @Daniel N solutions here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/707966/8650 can easily be adapted to only two cylinders. Daniel even writes how.

@hpekristiansen Can they be adjusted to show proper lighting? Right now each piece is ligthed as if the other did not exist.

@TeXApprentice: No. LaTeX does not have any ray tracing ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics) ) capabilities.

Just a thought. I wonder if this could be accomplished by running external software within LaTeX. (e.g. pythontex, sagetex). Then we could implement it. It sounds like a lot of hard work though. I also wonder if it is possible to implement ray-tracing software in LaTeX, though probably not. I certainly don't have the mathematical means at my disposal at my current stage of development in order to tackle such a problem. Still, I think that this capability would be very valuable, if it has not already been accomplished in LaTeX.

If one were to build any such a monster, it would be much easier to do it in Lua to be used in LuaTeX...but at this point if you have POV-Ray, Blender, ... providing much more, why would you go to that extent?

As I said, I'm not at a stage of mathematical development where I am able to tackle such problems, hence my lack of insight. Would it be possible to implement Blender features in LaTeX using pythontex, given that Blender is written in Python? Not the UI, but the ray-tracing features. This is just where my mind goes. You will have to forgive me for my inexperience.

I know you asked for a TikZ solution, but dealing with shading, iluminations, hidden pieces of the surface will be pretty hard to solve, even for this simple figure, within TikZ or even Asymptote.
So here is a solution within POV-Ray:

background { colour srgbt <0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0> }
     cylinder{ <0,0,0>,<0,2.5,0>, 1.00
          open
                texture { pigment{ color rgb< 5, 1, 1>  }// very light brown  
                // normal { bumps 0.5 scale 0.05 }
                   finish { phong 1 reflection 0.00}
                 } // end of texture 

          scale <1,1,1> rotate<0,0,90> translate<1.25,0,0>
        } // end of cylinder -------------------------------------           
     
cylinder{ <0,0.0,0>,<0,2.5,0>, 1.00
          open
                texture { pigment{ color rgb< 1, 3, 5>  }// very light brown  
                // normal { bumps 0.5 scale 0.05 }
                   finish { phong 1 reflection 0.00}
                 } // end of texture 

          scale <1,1,1> rotate<90,0,0> translate<0,0,-1.25>
        } // end of cylinder ------------------------------------- 

     intersection {
     cylinder{ <0,0,0>,<0,2.5,0>, 1.00
          open
                texture { pigment{ color rgb< 5, 0.80, 0.55>  }// very light brown  
                // normal { bumps 0.5 scale 0.05 }
                   finish { phong 1 reflection 0.00}
                 } // end of texture 
          scale <0.9,0.9,0.9> rotate<0,0,90> translate<1.25,0,0>

        } // end of cylinder ------------------------------------- 
     cylinder{ <0,0.0,0>,<0,2.5,0>, 1.00
          open
                texture { pigment{ color rgb< 5, 0.80, 0.55>  }// very light brown  
                // normal { bumps 0.5 scale 0.05 }
                   finish { phong 1 reflection 0.00}
                 } // end of texture 

          scale <0.9,0.9,0.9> rotate<90,0,0> translate<0,0,-1.25>
        } // end of cylinder -------------------------------------   
        }

  // orthographic (default) camera
camera {
  orthographic
  location  <1.5, 2.0, -2.0>
  look_at   <0.0, 0.0,  0.0>
}

// create a regular point light source
light_source {
  0*x                  // light's position (translated below)
  color rgb <1,1,1>    // light's color
  translate <-20, 40, -20>
}

You can see from start how it is much simpler to input a cylinder here than in TikZ, the additional options available and the automatic processing of light and shadows in the scene.

Awesome! The image is exactly what I was looking for. Is it possible to insert this code in the TeX file and have it processed by POV-Ray at runtime and the image inserted in the file, like in Asymptote?

@TeXApprentice, possible, of course yes. After all TeX is Turing complete, it can be programmed to compute just about anything -- but I am not sure that is a wise path to follow. Asymptote is part of LaTeX and of TeXLive. POVRay is neither and despite being mature has not been updated in over a decade. But this is another question entirely, not for here.
